# Div Classes & Background Image Not Working On CSS

Tags: html, css

I really suck at css, for some reason I just can't get any of the changes added in the code below to work on the document (however it is linked up properly to the HTML, if I change text color using the * attribute the colour changes)

So two problems - firstly, the div classes won't update at all, not one of the changes in it works, and I know the divs are set up properly in HTML (div class="services")

Secondly, the background image won't load at all, and I'm pretty sure I linked it properly.

```css
*{
  background-image: url ("file:\\\C:\Users\Dyldor\Desktop\dev\Landing 
    Pages\Fraud\finger.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

div.services {
  padding:20px;
  margin:20px;
  height:10%;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hi World</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css" />
  </head>

  <body> 
    <h1> Online Landing Page </h1>
    <p> Woo
     <br> <br>
     Sorry for hiding the text </p>
    <div class="services">
     <h2> Service One </h2>
     <p> Number 1
      <br> <br>
      Number 1 is a cool one
      <br> 
      I promise </p>
    </div>
    <h3> Want To Find Your Code? Get In Touch Now. </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can any of you give me some idea as to why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: remove white space. url("file...."); and Check twice path of background

Comment: I did that (it did change the color of the URL text on my editor) but it didn't add the actual image. The path is copied direct from my file explorer, I really don't get why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

For url or uri, you need to use forward slashes not backward. Check with forward slashes once.

Answer (score 0):

For css calls to a `<div class="services"></div>` you do not need to call `div.services` just `.services`...could you also by chance post your HTML code?

Comment: Added an edited version (text only, it's a work in progress for my business) - Will test out your suggestion now also!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between "(" and "url"

```css
*{
background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/mountain.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}

div.services {
padding:20px;
margin:20px;
height:10%;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
color:gray;
}
```

```html
<h1> Online Landing Page </h1>

<p> Woo
<br> <br>
Sorry for hiding the text </p>

<div class="services">
<h2> Service One </h2>

<p> Number 1
<br> <br>
Number 1 is a cool one
<br> 
I promise </p>
</div>

<h3> Want To Find Your Code? Get In Touch Now. </h3>
```